# Waiting for both completed tasks in iOS when one of them is animation?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, task, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I have a view which contains an image and I want to reduce the size of view with animation. Animation includes at least reducing of scale and translation and is performed via `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`.

On the other hand when the view becomes small I don't need such big image and I want to scale its size in pixels too. The scaling of image involves some additional calculations so it will slow down the current tread. So I need to run it asynchronously too.

So I have 2 async tasks and I need to replace the image with a new one when both of them are finished only. I can't simply combine them into a `dispatch_barrier_async` because they have various types. And I can't use a simple counter because I have a lot of such views and even one view may be scaled multiple times.

**Edited**

[PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/when) somehow suggest a simple way to execute 2 tasks and supports `animateWithDuration:...` methods but:

1. I haven't a possibility to include this whole library into my project (I can just copy small chunks of code due to my task);
2. It was rewritten in Swift which I can't use in my project (due to the task again);

Comment: If you will start scaling image on a concurrent thread after the animations is complete, and then when the concurrent scaling is complete assign it to the image view that you have, won't it satisfy your needs ?
In worst case you will have a large image a bit more(the time of rescaling) ?

Comment: No, it is not very appropriate for me.

Comment: Okay, then I think the issue is in: If the animation is incomplete but the rescale is so you have to wait for the animation , other wise you will assign asap right ?

Comment: If the animation is finished earlier then image assigning is called after the rescaling. If the rescaling is finished earlier then image assigning is called after the animation.

Comment: Well, you need a `BOOL` variable before animation is started make it `NO`
after it completed Assign `BOOL` to `YES` And make a signal (`NSLock` or something like `NSConditionalLock`), in the rescale thread check if `BOOL` is `YES` then just assign it otherwise Use `sleep` in While loop until you catching the `signal` from the `NSLock`.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Could you post some code as answer? But anyway I think the solution with GCD/NSOperationqueue exists and is simplier.

Comment: Sorry I am too lazy for this, but please read it here, it will definitely get you started because there is a nice example of `NSCondition` usage.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/index.html

Comment: So, you've got an image in a view and you want to make it smaller, but also load in a smaller version of the image (presumably in order to reduce memory usage). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, in my case it is possible a lot of pages. And the app sometimes falls down when their count is > 25. If you want to suggest to reuse views - it is not for my case because the situation possible when max count of views is displayed and all of them are visible at least partially. If you meaned loading from network then no, the original image is scaled (and some additional "heavyweight" actions). I also tried to replace the image until the animation ends but in this case I also should resize its container and it breaks the animation curve.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a single completion once two separate async task finish, you need to use dispatch_group

first you create your dispatch group:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
```

then for each of your async tasks, you will have them enter the group and leave the group in the completion block once the operation is done as follows:

```
// async operation 1
dispatch_group_enter(group);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do you operation 1
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
});
```

fire off the second operation in same manner

```
// async operation 2
dispatch_group_enter(group);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do you operation 2
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
});
```

and as many operations as you need

Once all operations are done, you will get a callback for the entire group and you can proceed with the overall completion:

```
dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
  // Won't get here until everything has finished
  // call overall completion
});
```

Also, if one of the tasks is animation, you'll want to dispatch onto main queue for that particular operation.

references used: 
http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/

Comment: You should add the following:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768527/how-to-know-if-several-blocks-have-completed-execution-before-taking-action   It describes how to do the same with `animateWithDuration:...` blocks. After this I could accept your text as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can test this code block with playground.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

// Views:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

// A box to move around in the view:

```
let box = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
box.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
view.addSubview(box)
```

// A label to appear when all animations finish:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: 360, height: 40))
label.font = label.font.withSize(50)
label.text = "All done!"
label.textColor = .yellow
label.textAlignment = .center
label.isHidden = true
view.addSubview(label)
```

// Create a dispatch group:

```
let animationGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

// Extend the `animate` function:
extension UIView {

```
    // wrap the animation duration method to give it group.
  static func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Void, group: DispatchGroup, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
    // Tell the group enter
    group.enter()
    animate(withDuration: duration, animations: animations) { (success) in
      completion?(success)
      // tell the group leave
        group.leave()
    }
  }
}
```

// Set the last animation's `completion` to `nil`.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
  box.center = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300)
}, group: animationGroup, completion: { _ in
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
    box.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/4)
  }, group: animationGroup, completion: nil)
})

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}, group: animationGroup, completion: nil)
```

// show the label after all the animations are complete:

```
animationGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
  label.isHidden = false
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```